# Can this be called a side effect?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Psychiatrist: *Here are the pills. You should be aware of the possible side effects. I can imagine the worst one being that you will have to continue coming to see me once a week.*

The psychiatrist is trying to be funny. Does the piece of dialogue work well? Or can sessions at the psychiatrist not be considered a side effect?

Comment: Since you know it's "not technically a side effect", what exactly are you asking here? Whether the joke is ***funny**?* That's a matter of opinion, not really about learning English.

Comment: A side-effect is any outcome that was not intended.

Comment: No, I'm asking if the fact that the patient will have to continue going to see the psychiatrist can be considered a side effect?

Comment: She knows how much the patient hates going there, so even though the side effects of the pills are bad she jokes that the fact that he has to keep coming to see her will be even worse for him.

Comment: It does seem mildly weird to me that the doctor doesn’t tell the patient what the *actual* side effects are, but that becomes the province of some kind of theoretical dialoguewriting.se (does that exist?), not ELL. Not sure how much we can help you.

Comment: The doctor does tell the patient about the side effects, I've just skipped the part in the post.